# Is there a way to restrict major version update for few jars in maven or jenkins build

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3

Is there a way to restrict major version update for few jars in maven or jenkins build. I want to restrict major version update for Spring jars. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talk about 'restrict', you should think of 'enforce', or in other words: the maven-enforcer-plugin. As far as I know, nobody has written such a rule. However, you can write it yourself. Have a look at https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html.
It short: you can get the dependency for a specific groupId + artifactId and verify its version matches your predefined or configured versionRange.

Comment: Thanks Robert Scholte for the reply. I am able to apply the rules now.